# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type ... has no index signature when accessing the object which key is an enum

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an object in state and I need to dynamically access its values inside the input component,

var selectedLangTab has a number type

I am trying to get a value by following:
value={userInput.translations[selectedLangTab].title

Error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ 0: { title: string; additionalInfo: string; content: string; language: Language; }; 1: { title: string; additionalInfo: string; content: string; language: Language; }; }' has no index signature.

```
translations: {
  [Language.CS]: {
    title: 'Title CZ',
    additionalInfo: '',
    content: '',
    language: Language.CS
  },
  [Language.EN]: {
    title: 'Title EN',
    additionalInfo: '',
    content: '',
    language: Language.EN
  }
}
```

interface of translations:

```
translations: {
[key in Language]: {
  title: string;
  additionalInfo: string;
  content: string;
  language: Language;
}
```

};

interface of Language:

```
export enum Language {
 CS,
 EN
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `translations` has the two properties (`0` and `1`) that come from the `enum` if you are indexing with `selectedLangTab` which is number there is no guarantee that the number will be in this range, hence the error.

You can defined `selectedLangTab` to be of type `0 | 1` or `Language` to make the error go away:

```
let selectedLangTab: 0 | 1 = 1;

userInput.translations[selectedLangTab].title
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/AQ4UwDwBwewJwC7gHYFcC2wAyBDZBzVHfMYAbwChRrgBhAZQBoqaQBRAORZAF8LvgAGzBJUAZzBwAksiiokAXnIDqCOHjGCcCAJYxkYgFzLWrANq4CREgDoGAXWOVTL4LoTDjAcgAqOj6S0AFpezK6mOAAmkf56yDiCMgBmMN6hKuHAAMb6CGDICGlhmdRaVsRgxpaEFXb0Gaw8xeEWeDW2nI4mJaDunsC+-sLAnOk9oFExuvoJyakDY+PZufmFC809Ze2V2G3WYDacDTR8LnwC56UibuoGWtMGTsdmANZgAJ7AOsi75SRdzkyfR2YjU33wAG5jtRJrEZolkCljKC4OCoSUcgVVsiwQR0ZktvsqnsKvjGhcoQJhEgJMIsnlItUfDgAEbGAAMwAAPsAAIzAJS8ynUcSSGRyBA2NQae5xMRmWlgelgRltZks+xSoZgIA)

Or you can use a type assertion to tell the compiler you are sure the number is in teh appropriate range:

```
let selectedLangTab: number = 1;

userInput.translations[selectedLangTab as Language].title
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/AQ4UwDwBwewJwC7gHYFcC2wAyBDZBzVHfMYAbwChRrgBhAZQBoqaQBRAORZAF8LvgAGzBJUAZzBwAksiiokAXnIDqCOHjGCcCAJYxkYgFzLWrANq4CREgDoGAXWOVTL4LoTDjAcgAqOj6S0AFpezK6mOAAmkf56yDiCMgBmMN6hKuHAAMb6CGDICGlhmdRaVsRgxpaEFXb0Gaw8xeEWeDW2nI4mJaDunsC+-sLAnOk9oFExuvoJyakDY+PZufmFC809Ze2V2G3WYDacDTR8LnwC56UibuoGWtMGTsdmANZgAJ7AOsi75SRdzkyfR2YjU33wAG5jtRJrEZolkCljKC4OCoSUcgVVsiwQR0ZktvsqnsKvjGhcoQJhEgJMIsnlItUfDgAEbGNDoFmSYBKACMlOo4kkMjkCBsag09ziYjMtLA9LAjLazJZwBwYl+23s4qGYCAA)